# *NOT* grouping photos on Timeline

Tags: facebook, image, fan-page

When we post several single photos within a short period of time via the API, the fanpage timeline groups these images together automatically.

Is there a certain length of time that you need to wait to ensure that the images appear separately within the page?

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14035704/1515819)

Answer (score 6):

This is intentional behavior to enhance the user experience on the Facebook Newsfeed. The photos are automatically grouped together to a nice album view rather than making multiple entries in the user's newsfeed which can appear spammy.

If you want to have the photos appear separately then you need to wait some time between posts. It is recommended  that you do not post too frequently to a page otherwise users may mark the posts a spam which has a negative affect on visibility of your future posts.

Comment: Thank Jonathan, do you know how long that waiting time is?

Comment: I don't believe that is published by Facebook so I can't help you there!

Answer (score -1):

i would wait 1 hr in between each post.