# Post object, status_type property doesn't work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

We're able to post to user's FB timeline/page as the page, no problem. The issue is the post that our app is posting is way smaller than post that a page/user can post to the feed manually.

We've tried to change status_type to one of mobile_status_update, created_note, added_photos, added_video, shared_story, created_group, created_event, wall_post, app_created_story, published_story, tagged_in_photo, approved_friend according to the API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) but neither of these change how the post looks in the feed.

Has anyone been able to post content to timeline/page wall through an APP that looks as if it was posted manually - specifically size of the image?

Sample page post that was posted through our app as page owner - image is small:

[image]

Sample page post that was posted manually - large image. We'd like the one above to look like this as well when posted through the app:

[image]

Comment: Can you show some screenshots so that people here can understand what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status_type` is set automatically. You can't set it yourself.

- In the case of the manual post, you added a photo. To do that in the API, you have to query `/PROFILE_ID/photos`.
- What you did through the API most probably is a post with a link, with the use of `/PROFILE_ID/post` with the `link` field filled. Hence, *Daniel & Co shared a link*.

That's why it doesn't look the same.

Some help for you to succeed at posting a photo:

- [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)
- [Adding Photos to Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/)
- [Disable grouping of photos on the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785120/disable-grouping-of-photos-on-the-timeline/14035704)

Also note that you won't be able to post a photo with the link to image which is hosted on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie. Yes I saw photos object as well and we're trying it as well to see how it ends up looking.